# Parachutes of Apollo and Crew Dragon capsules, what is different and what is the same?

Tags: apollo-program, dragon-v2, parachute

The number of main chutes is different, Apollo three, Crew Dragon four.

Both capsules used drogue and main chutes.

Apollo had two drogue chutes with single stage reefing.

Apollo used a two stage reefing system for the main chutes.

The main chutes of Apollo were pulled out by small pilot chutes.

Both the drogue and the pilot chutes of Apollo were ejected from mortars.

**Any other similarities and differences?**

Comment: I'm interested to know about differences with Gemini and Mercury too. Has a question on that been posted yet?

Comment: There is a technical note about the Gemini parachutes [NASA-TN-D-3496](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19660020968).

Comment: I think it was mentioned either in the SpaceX webcast by one of the presenters, or in an analysis video by Tim Dodd or Scott Manley that the either the lines or the fabric are made of a material that didn't exist in the Apollo era. I think it was the lines, which makes them lighter, stronger, but also gives them a little more flex and thus absorb the opening shock better.